# Change type of group of objects

Tags: python, variables, python-3.3

I need to convert a group of variables (result sets from BeautifulSoup) into strings. Is there an elegant way to do this to all of them at once instead of one by one? I was thinking something like this -

```
for name in [company_name, company_address, company_logo, company_cat, company_lat, company_phone, company_fax]:
    name = str(name)
```

I would also like to do a similar thing with re.sub -

```
for name in [company_name, company_address, company_logo, company_cat, company_lat, company_phone, company_fax]:
    re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', name)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for name in [company_name, company_address, company_logo, company_cat, company_lat, company_phone, company_fax]:
    name = str(name)
```

This will not work because you are modifying the list inside the for loop, you can however use a list comprehension for this, which is a one-liner:

```
list_as_strings = [str(name) for name in [company_name, company_address, company_logo, company_cat, company_lat, company_phone, company_fax]]
```

Demo

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> for i in a:
...     i = str(i)
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]


>>> b = [str(i) for i in a]
>>> b
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: This doesn't change the object type. Result of print (type(company_name)) <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>

Comment: @metalayer you cannot change an object's type. You can however reassign the new values to the existing variables: `company_name, company_address, company_logo, company_cat, company_lat, company_phone, company_fax = list_as_strings`, that will get the result that you want

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension should be faster but this solution can be more readable for you.

```
list1 = [company_name, company_address, company_logo]

list2 = []

for name in list1:
    list2.append( str(name) )

company_name, company_address, company_logo = list2
```

Now you have strings in previous variables.